# How do I skip the Opening Intro Videos without clicking?

Tags: rocket-league

When you start Rocket League, there are 2 annoying videos that start every time you launch the game, you can skip them by clicking the mouse button, but I'd like to skip them all together.

1. Is it Possible?
2. Is it also possible to automatically enter the "Press any button to start" Screen as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 
https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=486470487

Right click Rocket League in your library -> Properties -> Set launch options... -> Type ' -nomovie ' without the apostrophes -> Ok.

Don't know about #2.

Comment: What do you do to skip it on the ps4?